# Has Google Cloud Save been incorporated into the Games services?

Tags: android, google-app-engine, google-play-services, google-cloud-save

[This video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=KBhOkfbbZLk) makes a compelling case for Google Cloud Save but I'm a bit confused as to how I get it.  I went to the [Cloud Save page](https://developer.android.com/google/gcs/index.html) to sign up but the form just said that the EAP was over and they'd let me know when it was available.

This would've been simple enough except that if you go to the "Resolving Could Save Conflicts" page on the Android developer site, it [links to a page](https://developers.google.com/games/services/common/concepts/savedgames) which advises Game developers to switch from Cloud Save to the Saved Games service.

Is Cloud Save now a part of Games Services?  My application isn't a game but it will involve the storage of simple data objects per user so this feature would be nice to have.

Comment: Agree - I'm confused about this too.  And it seemed that Cloud Save was going to be their solution for easily sync'ing client data to the server, but now they've bought firebase.  I suggest you wait until Tuesday when they are having an event and will probably make some announcements and (maybe) clear up some confusion.

Comment: Had no idea about the Firebase addition - thanks!  And if I'm looking at the correct [agenda](https://www.gcp-live.com/), it does appear that some information will be shared during the 11/4 conference (1:00 - 1:50, track 2).  Guess we'll see...

Comment: Tom - I ended up missing the Firebase talk on the GCP live stream.  The parts of the video that have been published, though, seem to suggest that this will be the new sync solution for Android/App Engine.  If you want to leave a quick summary as an answer, I'll mark as accepted.

Comment: Ok, added it.  Note that the e-mail they sent out today says they will be publishing more on their blog soon.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes it is a part of google game services. It is called 'Saved Games' or sometimes 'Snapshots'. It uses Google Drive to store files privately (meaning only your App can access them). It is quite specific for games in its implementation (it supports screenshots and has 'play time' etc).

The documentation for it is here: https://developers.google.com/games/services/android/savedgames

---

Added after Cloud Platform Live event...

Google's new solution for easily sync'ing user data to the cloud and between devices is Firebase.  They [bought Firebase](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/2014/10/welcome-firebase-to-google-cloud-platform.html) in Fall of 2014 and 'presented' it at their Google Cloud Platform Live [event](https://cloud.google.com/events/google-cloud-platform-live/stream) on 2014-11-04.  The session that went into detail about Firebase is not available and there isn't much in the blog posts that went up for the event, but Google has sent an e-mail to attendees saying that they will be publishing more about their plans for Firebase on their [blog here](http://googlecloudplatform.blogspot.ca/).

What impact this has on the Google Cloud Save feature is uncertain, but it is note-worthy that Firebase received lots of 'air-time' at conference and I didn't hear cloud-save being mentioned.  Note that while they can both be used for the same purpose, GCS saves its data in the google DS while Firebase uses its own json datastore.

Comment: But they expanded it beyond that at IO14.  They added a feature that would allow you to save entities to the datastore directly from the client.